# Use PowerShell to search file directories in entire farm for a certain type of files

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

The issue is i need to be able to search an entire farm for .bak files i was wondering if it is all possible to be able to pull up a list and directory would like to use powershell though since we have a large farm and it would make it easier instead of going to single servers to do this im also extremely new to PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  It uses `Invoke-Command`, which requires that PowerShell remoting is turned on and working on all your servers.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -Credential adminusername -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\SearchHere -Filter *.bak -Recurse
}
```